# CSS: Let a child element with variable height and position absolute end at the top of the parent element?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, css-position

In a website I have a "dropup" menu at the bottom of a website.

Have a look at the following fiddle:

```css
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    width:200px;
}
.spacer {
    height:150px;
    width:auto;
}
ul,li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
a {
    color:#fff;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#e4003d;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul li ul {
    z-index: 8888;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: none;
}

ul:hover li ul, ul:focus li ul {
    display:block;
}

ul li ul li {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #e4003d;
    background-image: none;
}
ul li ul li a {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #e4003d;
    background-image: none;
}

ul li ul li a:hover, ul li ul li a:focus {
    background-color: #e4003d;
    color: #fff !important;
}

ul li ul {
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="spacer"></div>
<ul class="page-switcher">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sitamet</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://#">Ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://#">Dolor</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

When the menu is hovered I want the submenu to end exactly at the top of the `ul.page-switcher`. There is no information about the number of items within the menu or their height.

In the example I have used `margin-top:-100px;` but this is just for demonstration as the number of pixels is not fixed.

Need a CSS only solution and should keep the position absolute. How would you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `ul.page-switcher` `position: relative` and give the hidden `ul` position `bottom: 100%`

With this it won't matter the height of the *page-switcher* or the amount/height of the *popup* items.

Why this works is based on the fact that the absolute positioned `ul`'s `bottom: 100%` will be relative to its first ancestor having a position other than `static`, which in this case is the `page-switcher`.

Updated/Added CSS rules

```
ul.page-switcher {
    position: relative;
}

ul li ul {
    bottom: 100%;
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    width:200px;
}
.spacer {
    height:150px;
    width:auto;
}
ul,li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
a {
    color:#fff;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#e4003d;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul li ul {
    z-index: 8888;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: none;
}

ul:hover li ul, ul:focus li ul {
    display:block;
}

ul li ul li {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #e4003d;
    background-image: none;
}
ul li ul li a {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #e4003d;
    background-image: none;
}

ul li ul li a:hover, ul li ul li a:focus {
    background-color: #e4003d;
    color: #fff !important;
}

ul.page-switcher {
    position: relative;
}

ul li ul {
    bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="spacer"></div>
<ul class="page-switcher">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sitamet</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://#">Ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://#">Dolor</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  `position: relative;bottom: 56px;` `56px` is the height of parent `ul`

```css
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    width:200px;
}
.spacer {
    height:100px;
    width:auto;
}
ul,li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
a {
    color:#fff;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#e4003d;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul li ul {
    z-index: 8888;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 56px;
}

ul:hover li ul, ul:focus li ul {
    display:block;
}

ul li ul li {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #e4003d;
    background-image: none;
}
ul li ul li a {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #e4003d;
    background-image: none;
}

ul li ul li a:hover, ul li ul li a:focus {
    background-color: #e4003d;
    color: #fff !important;
}

ul li ul {
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<ul class="page-switcher">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sitamet</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://#">Ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://#">Dolor</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

Comment: Correct answer +1 but I prefer the answer of LGSon as it does not involve any concrete value in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a `min-height` and `position relative` to the first `li` element.

The submenue you have to set `position absolute` and `bottom 0`